# Only capture `character` when preceded/succeeded by `character`

Tags: php, regex, pcre

**RegEx**: `/@{0,1}\s*x(.*?)x\s*@{0,1}/`

The syntax I'm trying to force is `xSomethingx` and `@xSomethingx@` where spaces are allowed within the `@`'s but not `captured` when there's no `@`'s.

**Should match:**

`@         xSomethingx  @` **=>** `@         xSomethingx  @`

`.            xSomethingx                 .`  **=>**  `xSomethingx`

**What I tried so far**:
I've tried quite a few `looksaheads` and `lookbehinds` both `positive` and `negative` but I can only get it not to `match` whereas I don't want to `capture spaces` in that certain situation. I've also played around a bit with `non-capturing groups`.

Any pointers here? Can clarify more if need be.

Comment: Please provide some more examples. As of now, your question is rather vague and has multiple possible answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t7QdKO/1)

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/761508)

Regex: `(?:@\s*|)x(?:.*?)x(?:\s*@|)`

```
<?php
$pattern="/(?:@\s*|)x(?:.*?)x(?:\s*@|)/";
preg_match($pattern, "@xsomethingx@",$matches1);
preg_match($pattern, "@         xSomethingx  @",$matches2);
preg_match($pattern, ".            xSomethingx                 .",$matches3);
print_r($matches1);
print_r($matches2);
print_r($matches3);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => @xsomethingx@
)
Array
(
    [0] => @         xSomethingx  @
)
Array
(
    [0] => xSomethingx
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This one could also work for you:

```
(?:@\s*)?x(?:.*)x(?:\s*@)?
```

-

```
'@         xSomethingx  @'                  ; // @         xSomethingx  @
'.            xSomethingx                 .'; // xSomethingx
```

It's a little different than Sahil Gulati's regex, but it will basically perform the same match.

Comment: It's better to turn greedy dot to an un-greedy one `.*?` although I prefer `[^x]*` personally.

Comment: Really need the `OR` to be NULL. You'd expect not providing anything is the same but it's not. So, it doesn't perform the same match. Thanks though! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new best answer/pattern for you: `/(?:@ *)?x.*x(?: *@)?/`

This processes your string **nearly twice as fast as Sahil's** because his pattern makes the mistake of using pipes and a needless capture group.  You will see that I have used a greedy quantifier on the dot (like Eduardo) because if there is an `x` in the in the substring, then the pattern will not capture the entire intended string -- this is a potential failure in Sahil's pattern.

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/g5LltC/1)  (insert Sahil's pattern to see how it fails to fully match one of the strings.)

However, I would like to point out that all of the answers on this page are failing to validate that a captured string ends as it begins.  I mean, look at my regex demo, `@xsome@thingx` doesn't end with `@` but it does start with it.  To identify these occurrences properly, a more extensive pattern must be designed.  If this is a concern for you / your project, then you should clarify this in your question so that the answers can be updated as needed.